# Technique to get params on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, url, parameters

First of all I apologize for my poor English.

So I used these 2 ligns to recover the parameters in a given URL:

var queryString = window.location.search;

var params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

Sadly this URLSearchParams ain't compatible with IE, anyone would know a substitute who would give me the same value as params plz?